# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. Visualising BubbleSort in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I am trying to visualise bubble sort in react. Sorting works, and animation works. But after it finishes sorting, react keeps on throwing error.

[image: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.]

I have tried, `[]`, `[array]`, and `[array, picked]` in dependency array of useEffect.

- What am I doing wrong here?
- How do I visualise a bubble sort in react?

Code

```js
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import {Col, Container, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
    
    function isSorted(array: number[]) {
        return array.reduce((a: boolean, c: number, i: number) => {
            return a && array[i] <= (array[i + 1] || -Infinity);
        }, true);
    }
    
    function sleep(ms: number): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
    }
    
    function BubbleSort() {
        const [array, setArray] = useState([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]);
        const [picked, setPicked] = useState({a: 0, b: 1});
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (!isSorted(array)) {
                (async () => {
                    let temparray = array.map(x => x);
                    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                        let swapped = false;
                        for (let j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                                console.log(i, j, j - 1);
                                setPicked({a: j - 1, b: j});
    
                                const temp = temparray[j - 1];
                                temparray[j - 1] = temparray[j];
                                temparray[j] = temp;
    
                                swapped = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (swapped) break;
                        }
                    }
                    setArray(temparray);
                    await sleep(1000);
                })();
            }
        }, [array, picked]);
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <ShowArray array={array} a={picked.a} b={picked.b}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
    
    export default BubbleSort;
    
    interface IShowArray {
        array: number[]
        a: number
        b: number
    }
    
    function ShowArray(props: IShowArray) {
        const {array, a, b} = props;
        const out = array.map((v: number, i: number) => {
            const bgc = i === a || i === b ? "#f00" : "#ddd";
            return (<span key={i} style={{
                margin: "0.5em",
                padding: "1em",
                backgroundColor: bgc,
                display: "inline-block"
            }}>{v}</span>);
        });
        return (
            <>
                {out}
            </>
        );
    }
```

Update: It's still going.

[image: It's over 9000]

Update: I've tried React.memo for `ShowArray`

```js
const ShowArray = React.memo(function ShowArray(){...})
```

Update #3: Memo for BubbleSort, in hope it does something magical.

```js
const BubbleSort = React.memo(function BubbleSort() {...})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what I did wrong in code above. But I found another way.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

interface IBubbleSortState {
    original: number[]
    array: number[]
    i: number
    j: number
    compareI: number
    compareJ: number
    comparisons: number
    swaps: number
    done: boolean
}

function bubbleSortInit(): IBubbleSortState {
    const original = Array(10).fill(0).map(_ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    return {
        original,
        array: original.map((i: number) => i),
        i: 0,
        j: 1,
        compareI: 0,
        compareJ: 1,
        comparisons: 0,
        swaps: 0,
        done: false
    };
}

function isSorted(array: number[]) {
    return array.reduce((a: boolean, c: number, i: number) => a && c < (array[i + 1] || Infinity), true);
}

function bubbleSortStep(state: IBubbleSortState): IBubbleSortState {
    let {array, i, j, compareI, compareJ, comparisons, swaps, original} = state;
    // console.log({array, i, j, compareI, compareJ, comparisons, swaps});
    const len = array.length;

    if (compareJ > len - 1) {
        compareI = 0;
        compareJ = 1;
        i++;
    }

    const a = array[compareI];
    const b = array[compareJ];
    if (a > b) {
        swaps++;
        array[compareI] = b;
        array[compareJ] = a;
    }
    comparisons++;
    compareI++;
    compareJ++;

    // bails out quicker. Not a real bubble sort. Watching bubble sort is punishment.
    let done = isSorted(array) || i > len;
    if (done) {
        compareI = -1;
        compareJ = -1;
    }
    return {array, i, j, compareI, compareJ, comparisons, swaps, done, original};
}

function BubbleSort() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(bubbleSortInit());
    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => {
            if (state.done) {
                clearTimeout(id);
            } else {
                setState(bubbleSortStep(state));
            }

        }, 500);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <ShowArray array={state.original} a={-1} b={-1} done={state.done}/>
                        <hr/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <ShowArray array={state.array} a={state.compareI - 1} b={state.compareJ - 1} done={state.done}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}

export default BubbleSort;


interface IShowArray {
    array: number[]
    a: number
    b: number
    done: boolean
}

function ShowArray(props: IShowArray) {
    const {array, a, b, done} = props;
    const out = array.map((v: number, i: number) => {
        const bgc = i === a || i === b ? "#f00" : "#ddd";
        return (<span key={i} style={{
            margin: "0.5em",
            padding: "1em",
            backgroundColor: bgc,
            display: "inline-block"
        }}>{v}</span>);
    });
    return (
        <>
            {out}

            {done ? <span style={{
                margin: "0.5em",
                padding: "1em",
                backgroundColor: "green",
                display: "inline-block"
            }}>Done!</span> : ''}
        </>
    );
}
```

Based on https://decembersoft.com/posts/code-review-react-bubble-sort/